# set required field into a hide/show toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a toggle function which can hiding e.g input text or not.
I wanted to set a required in case of no hiding (but in case it is hided, it should no be required alert.

I tried to set into a id e.g test (see below) the `[required]` and a `window.alert` but is not working. Any suggestion how to solve this issue?

Thank you so much for your support and feedback

```
<tr>
    <td>Ice: </td>
    <td><input id="test" name="test" type="text" size="40">
    <button class="test btn" type="button" onClick="$('#test').toggle();">Hide</button></td>
</tr>   

$(".test").click(function() { 
   var lable = $(".test").text().trim();

   if(lable == "Hide") {
     $(".test[required]").text("Show").css( "background", "yellow").css ("color", "black").css("padding","1px 12px")
     return window.alert('please fill out');
     $(".text").hide().css( "background", "orange").css ("color", "black").css("padding","1px 12px");
   }
   else {
     $(".test").text("Hide").css( "background", "orange").css ("color", "black").css("padding","1px 12px");
     $(".text[required]").show().css( "background", "yellow").css ("color", "black").css("padding","1px 12px")
     return window.alert('please fill out');
       }

  });
```

Comment: what is `.test` and what is `.text`

Comment: @seethrough, i add the information above
test is the ID and text is the input field

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to set it to required:

```
$('.test').attr('required', '');
```

And to remove the required you can do:

```
$('.test').removeAttr('required');
```

Comment: than^k you for your support. you mean: replace $(".test[required]")

Comment: Yes :) That's how you add and remove attributes from elements.

Comment: Did you try to set some breakpoints to see if your code actually runs?

Comment: everything is running but i have just this little problem with this requirement :)

Comment: So did did you check in the DOM if required was added/removed?

Comment: required was not added or removed. the required only responded if i set it in the input tag. but then they can not be removed (is fix)

Comment: "the required only responded if i set it in the input tag"? You mean set it manually? Can you in the console just try `$('.test').attr('required', '');` and tell me if it added the attribute to the element...?

Comment: no i mean in the html element  `<td><input id="test" `  i put the required.. i to add it but isn't work.  I know your solutions works, but seams that with my solution it not